# Google Wallet Integration with the website

Tags: php, api, payment, android-pay

I’m trying to integrate Google Wallet into my website. I’m getting the message as below. Does anybody know why this happens? What should I do to resolve this issue? Please help me.

> Uh oh. There was a problem.
>
> We couldn't complete your purchase because of a technical issue.
>
> Details of the problem below: Unfortunately, we could not confirm your
>   purchase with the merchant's server. Your order has been canceled.
>   Please contact the merchant if this problem continues.

Comment: I got this error when I used GET instead of POST.

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that your server did not acknowledge the order notification from Google. Since you specified a postback url, Google will notify your server and expect a response within 10 seconds, otherwise the transaction is cancelled:

https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/postback

Note that you can also check the returned error code from the client side failure handler to determine why the transaction failed:

https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/jsreference#failurehandler

The Wallet for digital goods samples page has examples on how to acknowledge postback notifications:

https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/samples